# Is it possible to uncompress request/response body from Apache Httpd dumpio logs

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I'm working on a utility that scrapes httpd logs for request and responses to perform analysis on the JSON. I've enabled [mod_dumpio](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dumpio.html) for this.
The servlet sitting behind httpd sends gzipped compressed responses. I was wondering, is there an option for decompressing the bodies just in the httpd logs? I've tried `SetOutputFilter INFLATE` in my conf file, but that also decompresses the response to the client as well. I'd like to avoid performing decompression in my utility, thanks!